# Concise way to filter on two child attributes in ArangoDB (AQL / Spring Data ArangoDB)

Tags: spring-data, arangodb, aql

In ArangoDB I have documents in a `trip` collection which is related to documents in a `driver` collection via edges in a `tripToDriver` collection, and the trip documents are also related to documents in a `departure` collection via edges in a `departureToTrip` collection.

To fetch trips where their driver has a given idNumber and their associated departure has a startTime after a supplied date/time, I've successfully written the following AQL:

```
FOR doc IN trip
    LET drivers = (FOR v IN 1..1 OUTBOUND doc tripToDriver RETURN v)
    LET departures = (FOR v in 1..1 INBOUND doc departureToTrip RETURN v
    FILTER drivers[0].idNumber == '999999-9999' AND departures[0].startTime >= '2018-07-30'
RETURN doc
```

But I wonder if there is a more concise / elegant way to achieve the same results?

A related question, since I'm using Spring Data ArangoDB:  Is it possible to achieve this result with derived queries?

For a single relation I was able to create a query like:
`Iterable<Trip> findTripsByDriversIdNumber( String driverId );` but haven't had luck incorporating the departure relation into this signature (maybe because it's inbound?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your query only works if you have only one connected driver/departure for every trip. You're fetching all linked drivers but only check the first found one.

If this is your model it is totally ok, but I would recommend to do the `idNumber`/`startTime` check within the sub queries. Then, because we only need to know that at least one driver/departure fits our filter condition, we add a `LIMIT 1` to the sub query and return only a `true`. This is enough we need for our `FITLER` in our main query.

```
FOR doc IN trip
  FILTER (FOR v IN 1..1 OUTBOUND doc tripToDriver FILTER v.idNumber == @idNumber LIMIT 1 RETURN true)[0]
  FILTER (FOR v IN 1..1 INBOUND doc departureToTrip FILTER v.startTime >= @startTime LIMIT 1 RETURN true)[0]
  RETURN doc
```

I tested to solve your case with a derived query. It would work, if there wasn't a bug in the current arangodb-spring-data release. The bug is already fixed but not yet released. You can already test it using a snapshot version of `arangodb-spring-data` (`1.3.1-SNAPSHOT` or `2.3.1-SNAPSHOT` depending on your Spring Data version, see [supported versions](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/docs/Drivers/SpringData/GettingStarted/README.md#supported-versions)).

The following derived query method worked for me with the snapshot version.

```
Iterable<Trip> findByDriversIdNumberAndDeparturesStartTimeGreaterThanEqual(String idNumber, LocalDate startTime);
```

To make the dervied query work you need the following annotated fields in your class `Trip`

```
@Relations(edges = TripToDriver.class, direction = Direction.OUTBOUND, maxDepth = 1)
private Collection<Driver> drivers;

@Relations(edges = DepartureToTrip.class, direction = Direction.INBOUND, maxDepth = 1)
private Collection<Departure> departures;
```

I also created an working [example project on github](https://github.com/mpv1989/stackoverflow-51597981).

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer and example project!  I opted for the derived query approach, which works with `arangodb-spring-data` `3.0.0-RC.1`.  The example project also introduced me to Lombok @Data, so now I've thrown out a ton of getter/setter etc. boilerplate code :)